# Groupby multiple attributes and pass outcome/save to_excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df;

```
OpCode         PYear OperationStartDate
0    MCI6AF2   1993           2017-03-24
1    MCI6BF2   1994           2017-03-24
2    APJ5LFC   1975           2017-03-13
3    MQL0AF3   1986           2017-03-16
4    BMR3KFC   1982           2017-03-15
5    BRM1NFC   1981           2017-03-15
6    LNP5GF2   1987           2017-03-16
7       EAS5   1999           2017-03-22
8    HRK1DSC   1971           2017-03-17
9    HRK2FSC   1972           2017-03-17
10   NMI6BF2   1994           2017-03-22
11   NMI6AF2   1994           2017-03-20
12   HHY1JF1   1996           2017-02-01
```

I am able to groupby using one attribute 'opcode'to get minimum date in 'OperationStartDate'; pass that minimum date into a join and save the output to excel using;

```
df2 = df.reset_index()
df3 = df2.loc[df2.groupby('OpCode')['LastOperationDate'].idxmin()] #Try df3 = df2.loc[df2.groupby(['OpCode','PYEAR'])['LastOperationDate'].idxmin()]
```

## Rename df3 'LastOperationDate' column

```
df3.rename(columns={'LastOperationDate':'EarliestStartDate'}, inplace=True)


df3.drop(df3.columns[[0,4,1,5,6]], axis=1, inplace=True)


df6 = pd.merge(left = df, right = df3, how ='left', on ='OpCode')

writer = ExcelWriter('C:\Current Projects\Mapping\Python\Process Outputs\Example1321.xlsx')
df6.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
writer.save()
```

The issue is, if I groupby multiple attributes OpCode & PYear, I get a result that I can neither pass into a join nor save to excel. I am using the following alternative codes in this case;

```
df3 =df['Operation Start Date'].groupby([df['OpCode'], df['PYear']]).min()

df4= df.groupby(['OpCode', 'PYear'])['Operation Start Date'].apply(lambda x : x.min())
```

My result;

```
 Op Code                P Year                
ANN3EF1                1994                     2017-08-29
APJ5LFC                1975                     2017-03-13
APJ6EFC                1977                     2017-10-09
APJ6GFC                1976                     2017-09-04
APJ6HFC                1975                     2017-09-07
APJ6JFC                1977                     2017-07-27
AYN4RFC                1968                     2017-11-13
AYN6CF1                1984                     2017-03-31
AYN6CF3                1984                     2017-08-29
AYN6DF3                1985                     2017-09-05
AZZ7AF1                2004                     2017-08-04
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can pass this into the following join;

```
df6 = pd.merge(left = df, right = df3, how ='left', on ='OpCode')
```

OR add column title to the dates output

OR Save it to excel

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to join, you can simply do `transform` here:

```
# make sure the date is in correct format
df['Operation Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Operation Start Date'])

df['min_date'] = df.groupby(['OpCode', 'PYear'])['Operation Start Date'].transform('min')
```

Comment: Thanks @ YOLO. Changed it to:-



df.groupby(['Op Code', 'P Year'])['Operation Start Date'].transform(lambda x : x.min())

df["min_date"] = df.groupby(['Op Code', 'P Year'])['Operation Start Date'].transform(lambda x : x.min())

print df

Comment: @wwnde you don't need `lambda x : x.min()`, just do like in the answer above.

Comment: it throws a TypeError: invalid type promotion. It also poses challenges when I want to calculate min_date only when a condition-string is met – wwnde 26 mins ago

Comment: I still cant get that execute. The date is appropriately formatted.